# How to fix this value error ' ValueError: decay is deprecated in the new Keras optimizer'?

Tags: tensorflow, opencv, keras, computer-vision, face-recognition

I was following a youtube tutorial on Deep computer vision.

```
model = canaro.models.createSimpsonsModel
(IMG_SIZE= IMG_SIZE , 
channels= channel, 
output_dim=len(characters), 
loss='binary_crossentropy', 
decay=1e-6, learning_rate=0.001, 
momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
```

I also get the following error:

> ValueError: decay is deprecated
> in the new Keras optimizer,
> please check the docstring for valid arguments,
> or use the legacy optimizer,
> e.g., tf.keras.optimizers.legacy.SGD.

I am using Kaggle notebook. I tried downgrading tensorflow, using 'tf.keras.optimizers.SGD' and a few other things. I am new to deep learning and don't know how to fix it.

As a last resort, how can I modify the source code?

I appreciate the help : ).

Answer (score 1):

The error "ValueError: `decay is deprecated in the new Keras optimizer" occurs when using an old version of Keras that still supports the decay argument in the optimizer . To solve this error, you can try updating Keras to a newer version or using the learning_rate argument instead of decay in the optimizer.`

You can also try using a legacy optimizer from `tf.keras.optimizers.legacy` if updating `Keras` is not an option for you. For example:

```
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.legacy.SGD(lr=learning_rate, decay=decay, momentum=momentum, nesterov=nesterov)
```